# Error while building the webpack yarn run webpack:prod

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster

I am getting the error while building the production build for gateway in jhipster.

The command used for production build is: **./mvnw -Pprod package**

I am getting

```
  Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (webpack build prod) on project wvgateway: Failed to run task: 'yarn run webpack:prod' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

So as per the above command I used **yarn run webpack:prod** to build the webpack production build but getting the error

```
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.module.ngfactory' in '/home/kellhydcpu160/Documents/TestDeployment/optima_gateway/src/main/webapp/app'
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts 2:0-62
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
 error Command failed with exit code 1.
 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: version of jhipster : 5.0.1, node-v8.11.3. yes I have customized the generated code as per my requirements. and I tried by removing the node-modules. one thing I can say here is the development build is getting by the command **yarn run webpack:build** but it is not generating the production build by the command  **yarn run webpack:prod**

Comment: So it could be related to AOT compilation which is enabled only in prod build. Without a project to reproduce, it'll be difficult to debug as you said you modified code. Is this the first time you run a prod build on this gateway? Only advice I can give you is to compare with a freshly generated gateway.

Comment: yes Marziou, this is the first time I am running a prod build. If I run the prod build for freshly generated gateway it is working fine. but with my modifications it is not working. I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: When you don't have a continuous integration system, you must run manual prod builds manually from day 1 and often, in particular each time you add a new dependency. So now, you should use git to go back in history to the change you made that broke the build, once you know this it'll be easier to look for a solution.

Comment: Yes of course MaeZiou, but just one week back only I joined in this project where almost half of the coding is completed. do you think that the error is from java side ? or angular side? so that I can keep on adding one file and test the prod build.

Comment: It's on angular side. try using `git bisect run` to execute prod build on each commit until it succeeds, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect

Comment: Thank you Marziou, I will try this.